# Exporting JTable to txt file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

Interesting little error here, hopefully someone can point out what's happening to me.

My program is able to write to a text file if there's approximately 4 or less entries in the JTable.  Once there's more than that it fails and throws an exception that pops up my catch block.  Not sure what's happening.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("payrollData.txt"));
            PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);

            for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount()+1; i++)
            {     
                String headers = String.valueOf(outputTable.getColumnName(i));
                fileWriter.print(headers);
                fileWriter.print("\t");
            }   

            fileWriter.println("");
            for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); ++i)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<model.getColumnCount(); ++j)
                {
                    String s = model.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
                    fileWriter.print(s);
                    fileWriter.print("\t\t");
                }
                fileWriter.println("");
            }      
            fileWriter.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success. File saved to payrollData.txt");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failure");
        }
```

edit: added ex.printStackTrace(); and it shows an array index out of bounds exception

Comment: You'd know why if you quit eating the exception and read the error message. You're throwing away all of the information it would provide you in order to just display "Failure". What exactly do you think `Exception ex` means in the catch? It means you're being handed the Exception object in a variable named `ex`, and that object contains information about the exception. Use it.

Comment: Added a printStackTrace line to the exception and it's popping up an arrayIndexOutofBounds exception 4>=4

Comment: And the stack trace tells you exactly what line of code is throwing the exception. So set a breakpoint on that line and step through your code in the debugger, watching the variable values, and figure out why you're exceeding the bounds of the array. We can't do that for you, because we don't have the rest of your code or the file you're using with which to set things up. It's not like the invalid index is 2 billion; it's 4, which means you only have to step through the code 4 times to reach the pass when it fails.

Comment: I dont' actually have a debugger.  Would you recommend one?

Comment: I can't recommend anything. Your IDE doesn't provide one?

Comment: using Bluej  I'll see if it has one

Comment: If it doesn't, you're probably going to have to resort to writing output to the console on every pass that displays variable information. Old school debugging.

Comment: issue appears to be with the line String headers = String.valueOf(outputTable.getColumnName(i));

it's working just fine if i remove that and manually have the filewriter write the names of the headers. which don't change so should be fine.  just not sure what's wrong with it still.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's the `i < outputTable.getRowCount()+1`, specifically the `+ 1`, because most arrays and lists are zero based (meaning valid indexes are 0 to count - 1) and the `+ 1` exceeds the limit. Remove the `+ 1` and see if things work properly.

Comment: Actually added that in there because prior to that when it exported the headers to the file it was chopping off the last header and not writing it to the file

Comment: What does `i < outputTable.getRowCount()+1` have to do with the number of columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, having a look at this...

```
for(int i = 0; i < outputTable.getRowCount()+1; i++)
{     
    String headers = String.valueOf(outputTable.getColumnName(i));
    fileWriter.print(headers);
    fileWriter.print("\t");
}
```

I'm left wondering what `getRowCount` has to do with the number of columns ... pherhaps you meant `getColumnCount` ... which would means you could also get rid of the `+1`

## Observations...

Having spent some time running over the code, there are a couple of other minor observations I can make.

First, I'd highly encourage the use of [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), this will allow you to better manage your resources.

I'd also suggest using `StringJoiner` to generate each line, it's simpler then trying to check if you're writing out the last column or not and allows you supply what ever delimiter you want to use

As an example...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addColumn("Purpose");
model.addColumn("Name");
model.addColumn("Composition");
model.addColumn("Expiry");
model.addColumn("Stock");
model.addColumn("Cost");
model.addColumn("Type");
model.addColumn("Supplier");
model.addColumn("Supplier Number");
model.addColumn("Rack");

for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {

    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add("p" + index);
    vector.add("n" + index);
    vector.add("c" + index);
    vector.add("e" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("c" + index);
    vector.add("t" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("s" + index);
    vector.add("r" + index);

    model.addRow(vector);

}

JTable table = new JTable(model);

try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Test.txt")))) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        joiner.add(table.getColumnName(col));
    }
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
    bw.write(joiner.toString());
    bw.newLine();
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
        joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            Object obj = table.getValueAt(row, col);
            String value = obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString();
            joiner.add(value);
        }
        System.out.println(joiner.toString());
        bw.write(joiner.toString());
        bw.newLine();
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant upvoted and answer excepted.  Hate how small over sights like this make you scratch your head for a long time.  Thanks for looking it over!  Also, madprogrammer, you are everywhere! appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)